# How to add default value

Tags: java, list

I have a class that has a list. The user can add values to the List(String).But if the user does not want to add any values, then I want the list to get some default values that I will provide. But this default value should not be in the list if the user adds even one item(String).

I am new to Java so maybe the question is stupid...

This is my class!

```
public class StudentsList {

private ArrayList<String> studentList = new ArrayList<String>();




public void addStudent(String name) {
    studentList.add(name);                      //Giving the new student
}

public void printStudenList() {
    System.out.println("In this bootcamp you have " + studentList.size() + " students");
    for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println((i + 1) + "." + studentList);   //Printing how many students its in the course
    }
}

public void modifyStudentName(String currentStudent, String newStudent) {          //Finding the position to modify
    int position = searchStudent(currentStudent);
    if (position >= 0) {
        modifyStudentName(position, newStudent);
    }
}

private void modifyStudentName(int position, String newName) { //Change a name of student
    studentList.set(position, newName);
    System.out.println("Student name in position : " + position + " changed.");
}

public void removeStudent(String student) {          //Finding the position to remove
    int position = searchStudent(student);
    if (position >= 0) {
        removeStudent(position);
    }
}

private void removeStudent(int position) {
    studentList.remove(position);                     //Remove a student
}

private int searchStudent(String searchStudent) {
    return studentList.indexOf(searchStudent);          
}

public boolean onFile(String findStudent){        //Finding the position
int position = searchStudent(findStudent);
if(position >=0){
return true;
}
return false;
}
```

}

This is my main

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        boolean quit = false;

        int choice = 0;
        printInstractions();             //How to use the list

        while (!quit) {

            System.out.println("Make your choice ?");
            choice = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
            if ((choice >= 0) && (choice <= 6)) {
                switch (choice) {
                    case 0:
                        printInstractions();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        addStudent();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("Here is your list : ");
                        studentList.printStudenList();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        modifySudetntName();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        removeStudent();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        searchForStudent();
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        studentList.syntheticData();
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        quit = true;
                        break;
                   
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong choice.Read the instractions.Lets try again.");
                printInstractions();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you please clarify what you need? Maybe [edit] your question to include a code example of what you expect this to be called and what effect it should have.

Comment: maybe you can do something like:
`
if (values.size()==0){
return default;
}else{
return values;
}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
private List<String> studentList = new ArrayList<>();

// ... some code

public List<String> getStudentList() {
    return studentList.isEmpty() ? Arrays.asList("a", "b") : studentList;
}
```

Comment: for some reason i cant do it... it seems logic what you wrote.. but i doesnt work :D

Comment: finaly it worked thanks my friend :D

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```
List<String> listofnames = new ArrayList<String>();
 SillyJava(List<String> _listofnames){
    
    if(_listofnames.size()==0){
        listofnames.add("Some Default Value");

    }else{
        listofnames = _listofnames;

    }
   
}
```

Comment: SillyJava? what is that? :D

Comment: That was my class constructor. You can use its block logic in your method.